# File handling and windows store app development

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps

I'm a beginner to the windows app development. I'm trying to develop a windows 8 app which takes user inputs and store them in text files. Creating a text file and write user inputs to it is possible? I'm developing my app using Microsoft visual studio.

(I have tried file handling using Microsoft visual studio console application but I can't do it with visual studio store app.)

Answer (score 0):

Unlike desktop executables, Windows Store Apps can only access files from predefined sandboxed locations (E.g. the Video/Music library).

Read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx).

And [Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758325.aspx) the MSDN documentation for reading/writing textfiles.